# Hamcrest matcher comparing double value from JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-test, hamcrest

I'm using the Hamcrest `CoreMatcher` classes as part of `spring-test` integration tests. My JSON looks like:

```
{"data":[{"distanceInMiles":4,"id":"f97236ba-f4ef-4...
```

And my integration test looks like:

```
double miles = 4.0
Activity a = new BasicActivity(miles);
this.activityManager.add(a); // A mock activity manager (in-memory)
...
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/").accept("application/json"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data[0].distanceInMiles", is(miles)))
```

However, the assertion fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.data[0].distanceInMiles"
Expected: is <4.0>
     but: was <4>
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
```

I know that there's a separate `IsCloseTo` matcher here: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/IsCloseTo.html, but using it like so:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.data[0].distanceInMiles", closeTo(miles, 0)))
```

results in a strange error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.data[0].distanceInMiles"
Expected: a numeric value within <0.0> of <4.0>
     but: was a java.lang.Integer (<4>)
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
```

I was hoping to avoid having to include some kind of error - I *want* the returned value to be exactly `4`, I just don't care how many trailing zeroes are included.

Comment: The issue is that the `double` value is used to create the model object that is then checked for as part of the JSON response, so I was hoping to reuse the same variable to avoid typing it twice. I'll update my codeblock to demonstrate.

Comment: Are you using Java 8 by the way?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Java 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the match is performed on `Integer`s and not on double values.

You are correctly giving a `Matcher<Double>`. Spring uses Jayway under the hood for parsing the JSON and your JSON path will be evaluated as an `Integer` object. The matching will fail because an `Integer` and a `Double` are always unequal.

As such, you need to change your `Matcher` to `is((int) miles)`.

If you don't control the JSON you are getting and the `distanceInMiles` might change, this is more problematic. Jayway will parse `"4"` as an `Integer` but it will parse `"4.0"` as a `Double`. In this case, you will have to implement your own `Matcher` that handles both `Integer` and `Double` objects by extending `TypeSafeMatcher`. This would be a simple implementation:

```
class NumberMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Number> {

    private double value;

    public NumberMatcher(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        // some description
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Number item) {
        return item.doubleValue() == value;
    }

}
```

It matches any `Number` by comparing their double value to a known double value.

Comment: Unfortunately `closeTo` gave me some really weird problems as well - question updated.

Comment: @CraigOtis Yes, this is because it is still not the expected type. I forgot that Hamcrest does a type-check. You will have to implement your own matcher.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that by default is comparing as float, so try something like:

```
.body("field_with_double_value",is(100.0f));
```

Comment: and how to make such comparison work with double, not float?